# SSN validator - Differentiating digits and chars

Tags: python

this is my first time asking here in stack.
I have a question regarding this code:

```
ssn = str(input("Enter your ssn:"))

if (len(ssn) == 11 and ssn[3] == '-' and ssn[6] == '-'):
  print(ssn + " is a valid social security number.")
else:
  print(ssn + " is not a valid social security number.")
```

So the thing is, i thought this code was good if I typed in the normal format like 123-45-6789 and it would give me the correct print statement. However, i also noticed that if i typed in ddd-dd-dddd, it also gives me the logically correct print statement but i only want to work for digits.

Thank you so much in advance for helping me out, I'm currently a student and relatively young in the field of programming. Any outputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at using `regex` ? or are you opposed to using it ?

Comment: We haven't necessarily talked about regex yet, but Im open for new knowledge. But for now, I wanted to know how to code it in the most basic way possible. If that makes sense. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in python called `isdigit()` which checks to see if the string entered is a digit. We can use it along with taking a subsset of your string we can check if the other parts are digits.

```
ssn = str(input("Enter your ssn:"))

if (len(ssn) == 11 and ssn[0:3].isdigit() and ssn[3] == '-' and ssn[4:6].isdigit() and ssn[6] == '-' and ssn[7:].isdigit()):
  print(ssn + " is a valid social security number.")
else:
  print(ssn + " is not a valid social security number.")
```

Since you mentioned that you were new to programming, just to clarify a bit,
`ssn[x:y]` takes characters from index `x` upto (but not including) index `y` and allows you to treat it as a separate string.

Comment: This helped a lot, initially I was going to use the substrings == 1 or == 2 and so on. Again, thank you so much for your time and help, I truly appreciate it. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple regular expression for validating ssn number.

```
const validSsn = (value: string) =>
  value && /^(?!(000|666|9))(\d{3}-?(?!(00))\d{2}-?(?!(0000))\d{4})$/.test(value)
  ? true
  : false
```

Above code taken from [SSNValidator.org](https://www.ssnvalidator.org/)